# jedit unwanted conversion of english words to Greek Letters, Math and Logic symbols

Tags: jedit

Problem: Some English words are translated to symbols

1. Greek letters as English words are translated to symbols:

   - example `lambda` is converted to the equivalent small Greek letter.
2. Logic and Math words are transliated to symbols.

   - examples: `and`, `or`, `in`, `exists`, `sum`, `div`, `top`, `int`, `pm` converts to symbols 
          or small empty square if the symbol is not recognized.
3. Scope: Windows XP 32-bit, WIndows 7 64-bit with jEdit 4.5.2
4. This problem acts like an abbreviation expansion.  As I type a-l-p-h-a then a space, 
            jedit converts `alpha` to the small Greek letter alpha.
5. I have learned to live with this but would like to find a solution to the problem.
   Any help would be appreciated.  I don't know if this is a customization problem or a feature or a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn off all abbreviations, go into Utilities > Global Options, then Abbreviations. Uncheck "Space bar expands abbrevs".

**EDIT:** I didn't realize you wanted to use abbreviations but not those specific ones.

To take out the abbreviations for lambda, alpha, etc., go into that same dialog, pick "global" if it isn't already selected, then select each one from the list and hit the minus button under the list. Unfortunately (at least in jEdit 4.5) you'll have to select each one and delete it individually; you can't select multiple entries.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That eliminates the problem. However, it makes it a little more inconvenient to expand the abbreviations that I want.  I know that I can press Ctl-';

Comment: I took 9 minutes to type my previous answer and timed out.  Does everyone have this problem when they leave the space bar expansion active?  Your solution is better than typing 'andd ' and then backspacing to delete the extra 'd' or creating an abbreviation 'U' which expands to 'and '.  ('U' is German shorthand of 'und'.)

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks again for you help!  To test your advice, i changed the abbrev 'add' to 'addzzz' and that solved the problem.  (I did not want to delete these abbreviations, some day they may come in handy.)  Like most things in life, it is easy if you know how, thanks for sharing your knowledge with me!

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to check the checkbox next to my answer :)